# Access bokeh server URL

Tags: python, tornado, bokeh

I'd like to access my [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) application's URL.

I tried:

```
curdoc().session_context.server_context.application_context.url
```

But it only gives me the last part of the URL.

Also, when acessing the HTTP request object from

```
curdoc().session_context.request
```

Only the `arguments` member can be queried (as defined in https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request).

How do I get the complete URL of the running bokeh application?

Thanks

Comment: If you're running the bokeh app as a standalone module using `bokeh server` command, then you're stuck. See the [source code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/5a25b788dd0acb22b881a1a03023514383fb6a76/bokeh/server/application_context.py#L18-L26). It doesn't provide access to the actual request object, so you can't see the full url.

Comment: If you're running the bokeh app as embedded into a Tornado server, then you can try and monkey patch the [`_RequestProxy`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/5a25b788dd0acb22b881a1a03023514383fb6a76/bokeh/server/application_context.py#L18-L26) class to provide you the full url. But, I don't think it's worth the effort. You're better off constructing the full URL yourself like - `host + application_context.url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this does not seem possible when using the `bokeh server` command.

I managed to use `os.getenv('HOSTNAME')` and `session_context.server_context.application_context.url`  to rebuild the full url.

Thanks